# How to: Disable (and re-enable) a ToggleButton Event Trigger (Storyboard - Double Animation)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-style

I have a ToggleButton which, when clicked, slides out so the user can verify/edit the URL (textbox in button) they have copied (clipboard). The ToggleButton is then clicked again, which sets in motion various URL checks and slides back in to its original start position. This works perfectly. (code below).

What I would really like to do a this point is to disable this trigger. I want the button to not 'slide out', because on the next click it will download. So I'm trying to find a way to disable the trigger. When the file has downloaded all OK I'll re-enable the trigger to a state it was initially.

The togglebutton style starts like this (in my Application.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonURL" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
```

It sets various colour/font properties and the triggers of interest:

```
                <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Checked">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation From="-554" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" AutoReverse="False" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Unchecked">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="-554" Duration="0:0:0.150" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" AutoReverse="False" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

I'm just trying to find a way the enable/disable this trigger from code. Thank you if you can be of any help.

Comment: Have you tried setting the button's IsEnabled to false?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing at the moment. The problem is, the animation is so 'good' it still shoots out/in quickly. So you end up with a little kind of 'annoying effect'.

Comment: @KevinCook he wants he's button enable in order to do something different when clicked and not the standard slide action.

Comment: @video.baba did you try to put some condition inside you click event handler function? in order to stop it from sliding away upon certain condition

Comment: @Simo Yes, I have something checking the conditions and that is fine. It checks the condition (whether it's had the URL verifiied) and won't process the original code (as intended). Checked is set to false and it exits, it works. However.... It's like the trigger animation is so 'cool' and quick it beats me to it and does a quick 'out-in'.

Comment: so i don't understand where is the problem...

Comment: Have you tried using a flyout?

Comment: @Kevin Cook I don't know what that is, I'll go have a search and read.

Comment: I've just had a thought... It just so happens I have two ToggleButton styles which are identical, excluding the slide-out effect, that's just on the ToggleButton in question. I could change the style (from code) right? Sorry, not new to vb.net, just WPF.

Comment: e.handled = true is the first thing I tried but in the normal click event, I'll try your suggestion now.

Comment: @RavirajPalvankar Thank you very much - you got me on the right track. I initially went for the 'PreviewMouseUp' event and although it stopped the animation, it stopped all events it seems, couldn't even move the window/form. Once I put the e.handled in the "PreviewMouseDown', it worked a treat. Damn, I must remember those 'Preview' events, so handy. Please change your comment to an answer so I can mark as answered. Lastly, for the other contributors, thank you for your comments and time.

Comment: I'm glad it did. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the e.Handled = true of your event argument only on the condition when you don't want the animation to run. If that is still beating you with the quick in-out movement then use a PreviewEvent instead of a direct event.